# How to extract sub-string(s) from large string based on occurence of = in input string resulting in two lists based on occurence of = sign

Tags: python

Want to generate two lists from string of transactions based on occurrence/non-occurrence of = character in transactions making up the input string.  Transactions are result of 30 year old Basic program input.

New to Python and have spent more hours than I want to admit reading books, taking On-line courses and accessing web-sites.  Can not seem to get it through my brain.  Have referenced regular expression material, and still can not get anything to work.

'"  1197                         51.44FO +""   01                        5699.11=BB+"" 1198VOID                        .00MIS+"" 1179                          37.76UT+"'

This is a sample of the transaction data input string.  The = character designates a deposit transaction.  Transactions are separated(delimited by +").  Both deposits and check transactions seem to end with +" and start with "

I would like to have output of two lists.  One for deposits and one for checks.  I will then be able to do simple summaries/inquires of the two lists.

Comment: Its not entirely clear what you need here.  Can you provide an example the code you've tried out?  Also a clear expression of what you have versus what you want to see?

Comment: This is my latest attempt.  I want two lists output; one of deposit transactions and one of check transactions.  Deposit transactions entries have an "=" sign in the characters of the element.

Comment: My latest:  
s = '""  1197                         51.44FO +""   01                        5699.11=BB+"" 1198VOID                        .00MIS+"" 1199                          55.55FO +""   01                        4699.11=BB+""'
delimiter = '+""'
t = s.split(delimiter)   
for line in t:    
    count = 0
    dep = []
for i in range (len(t)):
    if "=" in (t[i]):
        print('This is a deposit:', (t[i]))
        count = count +1
        dep = (t[i])else:
        print ('This is not a deposit:',(t[i]))
print ("FOUND",count,"DEPOSITS")

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I entirely understand, but this does what I think you want:

```
deposits = []
checks = []
line = r'" 1197 51.44FO +"" 01 5699.11=BB+"" 1198VOID .00MIS+"" 1179 37.76UT+"'
bits = line.split("\"")
for i in bits:
    try:
        if i[0] == ' ' and i[-1] == '+':
            if '=' in i:
                deposits.append(i[1:-1])
            else:
                checks.append(i[1:-1])
    except IndexError:
        pass
```

Comment: Thank you!  When I try to run in Python 3.4.3 (old XP computer) I get "traceback": Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Stack_solution_1.py", line 6, in <module>
    if i[0] == ' ' and i[-1] == '+':
IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: @Sailored Should be fixed

Answer (score 0):

This is my latest code with input obtained here.  I expect there is better code that would be appreciated;

```
deposits = []
checks = []
line = '""  1197                         51.44FO +""   01                        5699.11=BB+"" 1198VOID                        .00MIS+"" 1199                          55.55FO +""   01                        4699.11=BB+""'
bits = line.split('+""')  #same as my code above
#print (bits[0])  #prints line
for i in bits:
    #print (i)
    if '=' in i:
        deposits.append(i[1:-3])
    else:
        checks.append(i[1:-3])
```